# Python - RFID read in a loop

Tags: python, rfid, reader

I am trying to make a python code that will read my the `RFID` card , and if he will not get any respone contine.

but I got stuck when he wait for a replay form the reader 
is there any **python** command that say something like:

```
while reader.available()?
```

this is the code I have (which is waiting for putting the RF tag)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import SimpleMFRC522
import time

reader = SimpleMFRC522.SimpleMFRC522 ()
OldText = ''

while True:
   # GPIO.cleanup()
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        status,TagType = reader.read_no_block()
        print(status)
        if status == 'None':
            print ("No Card Found")
        elif status != 'None':
            id,text = reader.read()
            if text != OldText:
                print(text)
                OldText=text

            else:
                print ("Same card")

    finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
    time.sleep(5)
```

this is the Fix code - 
but on the shell I don't get the "No card found" - why?
this is the output I'm getting now :

```
675036844849
new test 13.9.18                                
None
Same card
MFRC522-python/ReadOnce.py:28: RuntimeWarning: No channels have been set up yet - nothing to clean up!  Try cleaning up at the end of your program instead!
  GPIO.cleanup()
None
Same card
None
Same card
None
Same card
None
White_Card                                      
None
Same card
None
Same card
None
```

if no card is on the RFID - it get stuck....
why?

Comment: can you help some more?  I guess I need to understand this part def read(self):
      id, text = self.read_no_block()        
      while not id:
          id, text = self.read_no_block()  
      return id, text              - but what do I need to get from this?

Comment: None is a keyword. Check this link to understand on its usage - https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-none-keyword-in-python

Answer (score 1):

`print (status == None)` will return true.

`print (status == 'None')` will return false.

Therefore use:
`if (status == none)`

Comment: if status is None: would be much better

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    try:
        # your code here
    except:
        pass
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Should sort you, let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: not working yet - I still don't get "No Card Found" when nothing is near the RFID - i get print "None" but not the "No Card Found". how come?

Comment: Add logging before every line, see where it's barfing.

Comment: how do I do this? , this is my first python experience... Thanks ,

Answer (score 0):

Hello my friend I just looked at the code and your mistake was using <# "None" # >, a mistake that took me a while to notice, you should have used just <# None #>. The difference is that one is a string and the return value of the function isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pyembedded` python library for this which can give you the tag id when the rfid card is scanned.

```
from pyembedded.rfid_module.rfid import RFID
rfid = RFID(port='COM3', baud_rate=9600)
print(rfid.get_id())
```

https://pypi.org/project/pyembedded/